# typedef'd STL container type as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I was wondering if it's possible to use a typedef'd container as a template parameter.  I'm trying something like the following:

```
template<typename T>
using containerT = std::vector<T>;

template <template<class T, class = std::allocator<T> > class container_type = containerT >
struct nodeData {
    container_type<int> param;
};

int main()
{    
    nodeData<> nd;
}
```

This results in a compile error with GCC 4.8:

> expected a template of type 'template class
>   container_type', got 'template using containerT =
>   std::vector< T >'

Anybody know of a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`containerT` has only one template parameter, so the template template parameter must match:

```
template <template<class> class container_type = containerT >
```

However, I suspect you want to be able to take the standard containers as template arguments, so you want this instead:

```
template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
using containerT = std::vector<T, Allocator>;
```

Now you can use `containerT` as a template argument for the function template you gave in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap a template in a type, delaying its instantation. This makes templates first class citizens in the metaprogramming world:

```
template<template<typename...> class T>
struct wrapper
{
    template<typename... ARGS>
    using instance = T<ARGS...>;
};

template<typename WRAPPER , typename... ARGS>
using instance = typename WRAPPER::template instance<ARGS...>;
```

Now you could use wrappers as type optional template parameters:

```
using container_type = wrapper<std::vector>;

template <typename CONTAINER = container_type>
struct nodeData {
    instance<CONTAINER,int> param;
};
```

Now your use case works perfectly:

```
int main()
{
    nodeData<> node;
}
```